# struct definition within a struct

Tags: c, struct

Is it possible to not only embed a structure but define within the structure as well in C?

```
struct Student { 
    char *name;
    struct Student *next;
};

struct School {
    struct Student *Students; // definition and embedding inline possible?
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you asking about. What is "embedding inline"? There's no "embedding" in your code since all fields are pointers.

Comment: While AnT's answer is correct and you can do this, other people might find your code difficult to read and may not be pleased with you for writing your code this way.

Comment: @DietrichEpp It's just that there's no use of it outside the .h .c file, It's a consideration, by the way based on the answer, is there a way to access the type of this inline struct, for instance `School::Student` or `School.Student`?

Comment: When you access it outside the struct it is still just `struct Student`. Putting it inside `School` hasn't changed the way it's named.

Comment: @DietrichEpp thanks for the clarification. I take your input for code readability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to fully declare a struct type inside another struct type's declaration as long as you are immediately using the inner struct declaration to declare a field. Your declarations can be rewritten as

```
struct School {
  struct Student { 
    char *name;
    struct Student *next;
  } *Students;
};
```

`struct Student` is still a file-scope type, just as in your original code. And there's not much point in doing it that way since it is much less readable.

Comment: Let's say this struct is defined in .h file, can I access the type within the .c file as `School.Student` ? I see some code hints like `School::Student` in my IDE?

Comment: @App2015: No. This is C. As I said already, the types you'll have declared in this case are `struct Student` and `struct School`. The types are not nested in any way. The end result is exactly the same as in your original code.

Comment: so this is invalid in C? `struct School::Student *student`

Comment: @App2015: Yes, this is invalid in C.